# How to change the innerHTML of the current element?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print a text on the current element. I tried these two codes, but they doesn't seem to work:

This one is printing the text in the whole document:

```html
<div>
  <script>
    fetch('file.txt').then((resp) => resp.text()).then(function(data) {
      document.write(data);
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Resulting in this:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- THE TEXT THAT I REQUESTED APPEARS HERE -->
  </body>
</html>
```

---

And the code below is returning the following error:

```html
<div>
  <script>
    fetch('file.txt').then((resp) => resp.text()).then(function(data) {
      document.this.innerHTML(data);
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

> Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML = data;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `this` with `body`. `innerHTML` is not a function its a property you need to set it.

I think you want to append to the `<div>` in which the `<script>` us present. You can access the script and get its `parentNode`

```
<div>
  <script>
    const script = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
    fetch('file.txt').then((resp) => resp.text()).then(function(data) {
      script.parentNode.innerHTML = data;
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

**Note:**`document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1]` will get the current `<script>` tag because it will be lastest script executed.

Comment: I think he wants to write this to the current div... This will write to the body.

Comment: As explained above, I want to print the text on the current element, that in this case is `<div>`, not on `<body>`.

Comment: simply replace document.body with 'selector for the current div'. In your HTML exameple, you are showing that you want it appended directly to the body.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I have updated the answer. I misunderstood at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.writeln()` to write within the current div

```
<div>
  <script>
    fetch('file.txt').then((resp) => resp.text()).then(function(data) {
      document.writeln(data);
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Hre is a similar example demonstrating the result.

```html
<div>
  <script>
    Promise.resolve('abc123<br>xyz789')
    .then(function(data) {
      document.writeln(data)
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should move the script out of the div and then replace 'this' in your code with a reference to the target div.

If you give your div an id of 'target' you could do the following:

```
const target = document.getElementById('target');

fetch('file.txt').then((resp) => resp.text()).then((data) => target.innerHTML = data);
```